# Kotlin Array creation: No value passed for parameter 'init'

Tags: kotlin, android-studio-3.0, kotlin-android-extensions

I am converting a Java file into Kotlin in Android Studio and I am getting this error:

> No value passed for parameter 'init'

I modified the code slightly by adding **lateinit**

The java code is:

```
 private TextView[] dots;
 private int[] layouts;

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage)
{
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length]; 
    //some lines here
}
```

And corresponding Kotlin code is

```
private lateinit var dots: Array<TextView>
private lateinit var layouts: IntArray

private fun addBottomDots(currentPage: Int)
    {
       dots = Array<TextView>(layouts.size) // error happens here
       // some lines here

    }
```

As I am new in Kotlin, I can't figure out why this is the reason

Answer (score 6):

Check the Array constructor: `public inline constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)` - that's why error happens.

Guess you want to create ArrayList

```
dots = ArrayList<TextView>(layouts.size)
```

Comment: An alternative could be
        
        `dots = Array<TextView>(layouts.size, init= {i:Int -> null})`
        
Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

The code is not equivalent. Your original code actually represents the type `var dots: Array<TextView?>` since the values of the array may be uninitialized.

Because you defined it as non-null, the only available constructor for `Array` requires a function to initialize all elements to a non-null value. You can either provide this or change the type to be nullable and use `dots = arrayOfNulls(layouts.size)`

Comment: You are right, I changed this code slightly. But where is the problem in here?

Comment: You are creating an array of non-null values without providing the non-null values.

Comment: The problem exists because Kotlin requires strict nullability in its types. By default Java arrays are filled with `null` so they cannot be anything but arrays of a nullable type. To safely create non-nullable arrays the library provides ways to ensure it is immediately filled with non-null values to satisfy the non-null requirement.

Comment: Then what should I change in code?   I instantiated layout variable in oncreate() method @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: Can all the elements be initialized when the array is created? Then use the non-nullable constructor to initialize it all at once. Are they only progressively available? Then you have no choice but to use a nullable array and checking during access to ensure null safety.

Comment: it's correct answer